# In-App purchase iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a number of questions about the in-app purchase in iOS:

1- Can I test the functionality without a banking and tax agreement?

2- Will the in-app purchase section in app submission ( under General App Information)appear after the banking agreement because so far the section is not there.

3-How many days i have to wait until the bank info are approved (so far it has been 5 days and this message still showing"Note: Banking update in progress, your changes should be reflected within 24 hours.
You will not be able to make any changes until your update completes processing.")

4- Invalid Product Id is the response when i request the products, is this because of the unfinished banking agreement?

Note: In-app purchase in On in capabilities.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can not test IAP without banking and tax agreement.
2. Yes, After fill banking and tax detail showing IAP section in general section.
3. After filling bank and tax details in itunesconnect. you can test within hour.
4. Yes, Invalid product is showing because of not filled bank details.

Comment: I did a test after filling the banking agreement but the result is Invalid product Id although i checked and i am using the exact same product id. Could the problem be the approval of bank info?

Comment: Showing status waiting for review or missing metaData into IAP page.

Comment: The IAP is in ready to submit state, the IAP section did appear , do i need to add a binary version to be able to test the feature?

Comment: Not required binary.